# Welcome message embed Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I try to do welcome message embed with avatar
and its say to my TypeError: guildMember.displayAvatarURL is not a function

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd' , guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "778565734217416711")
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('802194812521939006').send(embed)
    embed.setTitle(`<@${guildMember.user.id}> ברוך הבא`)
    embed.setDescription(`<@${guildMember.user.id}> ברוך הבא לשרת המטורף הזה`)
    embed.setThumbnail(guildMember.displayAvatarURL())
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display the avatar of a GuildMember object, but would first have to convert it to a User object.

#### Final Code

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd' , guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "778565734217416711")
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('802194812521939006').send(embed)
    embed.setTitle(`<@${guildMember.user.id}> ברוך הבא`)
    embed.setDescription(`<@${guildMember.user.id}> ברוך הבא לשרת המטורף הזה`)
    embed.setThumbnail(guildMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
});
```